# How to install apache beam SDK for python on a local computer

Tags: python, apache-beam

I got quite confused by trying to figure out how to install apache beam SDK for python, from what I searched via different documentations, after downloading the SDK from PiPy, this command needs to run in order to install the SDK locally (the following command is in powershell as seen in documentation):

PS> python -m pip install apache-beam

However, my question is, how does pip know where is the apache-beam sdk located on my local computer after it is downloaded?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some standard install directories / paths where pip  downloads the packages, some of these are:

```
/home/<user>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/<virtualenvpath>/envs/dev/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

you can check where pip has installed a particular package using the following command:

```
pip show <package_name>
```

Comment: Sorry, my question is, will pip be able to locate the apache beam SDK regardless of where it is downloaded on a local PC before installing it? Hope my question is clear. Thanks.

Comment: no, if you download it to any random location, it will not be able to find it